# tmux: hangs and do not load, and do not respond to any option command

Tags: linux, tmux

I have installed tmux from source on my localspace in Fedora. It was working nicely so far. But suddenly can not run it anymore, when run tmux, it just halts. Tried different command options like ls-sessions, none works. Killed all the processes of my user, deleted all the files of tmux and `libevnet`, and reinstalled them again from scratch. Still same, and tmux command in terminal just freezes without any actual error.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/a/625531/50710 for another answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks.
I found the problem. The tmux process were in D state, and I had no choice but to reboot the system. 
The problem came from kerberos ticket expiring after a while. And find a scripts that solves this problem:
https://iain.cx/src/ktmux/

Comment: Mine was not hanging in D state, it was just sleeping. `kill -9` helped.

Answer (score 74):

I had faced this problem for a long time and after a bit of searching I figured out that this was being caused because I accidently hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> is my shortcut for switching panes), and this turns off flow control in terminals and stops the terminal from accepting input. It can be reenabled by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>.

**Source:** https://superuser.com/a/553349/137226

Comment: This saved my session!

Answer (score 47):

Had a similar issue, where I had a tmux session with two buffers. I didn't see anything I typed, but when I switched between buffers what I had typed previously would appear onscreen. `stty sane` didn't work.

I detached <kbd>Ctrl-b</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>, and noticed that there was still a client attached when I looked at `tmux list-clients`. `tmux detach-client` removed it, and then I could reattach and the everything worked again.

Comment: Wow! that solved a problem I encounter too often... thanks

Comment: Was the extra client a fluke?

Comment: Thank you!!!! You are single who gave right answer.

Answer (score 19):

If it is ok to lose your sessions, try deleting the `tmux-NNNNNNN` directory, where `NNNNNNN` is a number, under your `/tmp` directory. According to the `tmux` manual, if the `TMPDIR` environment variable is set, the `tmux-NNNNNNN` will be put in the `TMPDIR`.

> tmux stores the server socket in a directory under /tmp (or TMPDIR if set);

This solved my problem of not being able to run `tmux` commands that are related to sessions. I also tried the following, but they did not work:

- `killall -9 tmux`
- reinstall `tmux`
- restart shell session

I could not easily restart the operating system, because it's a shared server managed by others.

Comment: This worked for me as tmux was hanging as soon as I was trying to launch it in terminal.

Comment: Deleting the /tmp/tmux-NNNNNNN folder helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

`tmux` was halting right after I started it. <kbd>Ctrl-Q</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> didn't do anything.

Fixed with

```
killall -9 tmux
```

(May be a different problem, but this question showed up in Google.)

Comment: `tmux` was running here since Nov 8 (5 weeks), only `kill -9` did help too. `ps waxl` showed it was in a deep sleep: `1  3605 16359     1  20   0  33004  4156 n_tty_ Ss   ?         41:37 tmux`. Do you remember your flags?

Comment: Nope. But I will check `ps waxl` next time this happens.

Comment: At least get a stack trace. Otherwise killing it is as much of a fix as shutting off the computer. If you expect it to happen again - which you probably should - you can also configure Tmux to log its buffer to a file so you can do a bit of a post-mortem.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue. The cause is that the `tmux` buffer is full, and it also may happens cause of multi clients to the `tmux` session.

To solve it you need to detach all the clients from the session, and reattach it.

The best way I found to solve it is to add to the `~/.bashrc` file this functions:

```
check_params() {
       if [[ $1 < $2 ]]; then
               echo -e "Usage:\n${3}"
               ok=0
       else
               ok=1
       fi

}

# detach all the clients from this session, and attach to it.
reattach_client() {
       check_params $# 1 "reattach_client <tmux_session_name>"
       if [[ $ok == 1 ]]; then
               tmux list-client | grep $1 | awk '{split($1, s, ":"); print s[1]}' | xargs tmux detach-client -t | true
               tmux attach -t $1
       fi
}
```

then run `source ~/.bashrc` to make these changes in the terminal.

Now to attach the session type:

```
reattach_client <session_name>
```

solved my issue.

Thanks to Alex Zelichenko for help me with this!

Comment: I had two tmux sessions which where working fine, but any tmux command in a new shell hanged. Detaching from the running tmux sessions solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: What if you don't know the session name?

Comment: You can list the sessions with the command: "tmux list-sessions" or with the shortcut "tmux ls". Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to narrow down your problem a bit with a few of these tests:

1. Give it a shot from outside X11: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> (or use `ssh` from another computer)
2. Test if other terminal emulators work: `script` and `screen`
3. Try another complicated terminal application: `htop` and `mc`
4. Reset your TTY settings: `stty sane`
5. Check that your terminal identified: `echo $TERM` (it should be something like "xterm" or "linux")
6. Make that your terminal capabilities file exists: `ls -lh /usr/share/terminfo/*/$TERM`

Answer (score 2):

A less drastic action (to try before killing the tmux process) is to ssh into the machine and run the following command.

```
kill -CONT `pidof tmux`
```

Source: https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/507#issuecomment-271502093

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me because I accidentally tried to create two parallel tmux sessions with the same name.

What worked for me was to enter `htop`, checking pid's of the two running commands that created the sessions, and killing both by using `kill -9 pid1` and `kill -9 pid2`