# tmux does not start when using tty (ubuntu 11.10)

Tags: ubuntu, tty, tmux

I went through this similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/a/7410228/880040 and the 6th thing to check,

> Make that your terminal capabilities file exists: `ls -lh /usr/share/terminfo/*/$TERM`

Is what doesn't pass. This entire folder is empty. tmux works as expected when starting it from a ssh session. On the tty session, it just hangs on a newline after the tmux command. Cannot kill it with ctrl-c either, have to ssh in and killall tmux.

$TERM is 'linux'
OS is Ubuntu 11.10 (server edition) 32 bit

Unfortunately the above post did not explain what to do if /usr/share/terminfo was empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ubuntu, the various `terminfo` files are provided by `ncurses-base`<sup>1</sup> - you might first want to try reinstalling to see if that fixes your issue.

If that doesn't work, you can always copy the working `terminfo` (from the box you are SSH'ing from) across to your Ubuntu machine.

First, establish that you do not have an entry for `linux` on the Ubuntu box:

```
infocmp linux
```

Then, on the machine that you SSH from, make a copy of the `terminfo`:

```
infocmp linux > linux
```

copy it to your remote machine with `scp` and then, on the remote machine, install it with:

```
# tic /path/to/linux
```

You should also consider installing `screen-256color` as this is the `terminfo` tmux works best with.

1. http://packages.ubuntu.com/ko/natty/ncurses-base